# After upgrading from Sql Server 2008 to Sql Server 2016 a stored procedure that was fast is now slow

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, sql-server-2016

We have a stored procedure that returns all of the records that fall within a geospatial region ("geography").  It uses a CTE (with), some unions, some inner joins and returns the data as XML; nothing controversial or cutting edge but also not trivial.

This stored procedure has served us well for many years on SQL Server 2008. It has been running within 1 sec on a relatively slow server.  We have just migrated to SQL Server 2016 on a super fast server with lots of memory and a super fast SDDs.

The entire database and associated application is going *really fast* on this new server and we are very happy with it.  However this one stored procedure is running in 16 sec rather than 1 sec - against exactly the same parameters and exactly the same dataset.

We have updated the indexes and statistics on this database. We have also changed the compatibility level of the database from 100 to 130.

Interesting, I have re-written the stored procedure to use a temporary table and 'insert' rather than using the CTE.  This has brought the time down from 16 sec to 4 sec.

The execution plan does not provide any obvious insights into where a bottleneck may be.

We are a bit stuck for ideas. What should we do next?  Thanks in advance.

--

I have now spent more time on this problem than i care to admit. I have boiled down the stored procedure to the following query to demonstrate the problem.

```
drop table #T 

declare @viewport sys.geography=convert(sys.geography,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

declare @outputControlParameter nvarchar(max) = 'a value passed in through a parameter to the stored that controls the nature of data to return. This is not the solution you are looking for'

create table #T
    (value int)

insert into #T 
select 136561 union 
select 16482 -- These values are sourced from parameters into the stored proc

select 
      [GeoServices_Location].[GeographicServicesGatewayId],
      [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Lat,
      [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Long

      from GeoServices_Location

      inner join GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway
            on    GeoServices_Location.GeographicServicesGatewayId = GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway.GeographicServicesGatewayId

      where 
        (
            (len(@outputControlParameter) > 0 and GeoServices_Location.GeographicServicesGatewayId in (select value from #T)) 
            or (len(@outputControlParameter) = 0 and GeoServices_Location.Coordinate.STIntersects(@viewport) = 1)
        )
        and GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway.PrimarilyFoundOnLayerId IN (3,8,9,5) 

GO
```

With the stored procedure boiled down to this, it runs in 0 sec on SQL Server 2008 and 5 sec on SQL Server 2016

http://www.filedropper.com/newserver-slowexecutionplan

http://www.filedropper.com/oldserver-fastexecutionplan

Windows Server 2016 is choking on the Geospatial Intersects call with 94% of the time spent there. Sql Server 2008 is spending its time with with a bunch of other steps including Hash Matching and Parallelism and other standard stuff.

Remember this is the same database.  One has just been copied to a SQL Server 2016 machine and had its compatibility level increased.

To get around the problem I have actually rewritten the stored procedure so that Sql Server 2016 does not choke.  I have running in 250msec. However this should not have happened in the first place and I am concerned that there are other previously finely tuned queries or stored procedures that are now not running efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

--

Furthermore, I had a suggestion to add the traceflag -T6534 to start up parameter of the service.  It made no difference to the query time. Also I tried adding option(QUERYTRACEON 6534) to the end of the query too but again it made no difference.

Comment: well, without seeing the plan or schema it's hard to tell....

Comment: The stored procedure may be a victim of the new cardinality estimator that was introduced in SQL Server 2014. Try using the `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)` trace flag in your query. This will force it to use the old estimator. If the SP runs normally then the new cardinality estimator makes the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I did not know about that.  Unfortunately it made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: It sounds silly but did you check to make sure your indexes all moved for the appropriate tables? Occasionally migrations miss something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion HLGEM. Yes. I have even dropped the spatial index and recreated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the query plans you provided I see that spatial index is not used on newer server version.
Use spatial index hint to make sure query optimizer chose the plan with spatial index:

```
select 
    [GeoServices_Location].[GeographicServicesGatewayId],
    [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Lat,
    [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Long
from GeoServices_Location with (index ([spatial_index_name]))...
```

I see that the problem with the hint is OR operation in query predicate, so my suggestion with hint actually won’t help in this case.
However, I see that predicate depends on @outputControlParameter so rewriting query in order to have these two cases separated might help (see my proposal below).
Also, from your query plans  I see that query plan on SQL 2008 is parallel while on SQL 2016 is serial. Use option (recompile, querytraceon 8649) to force parallel plan (should help if your new superfast server has more cores then the old one).

```
if (len(@outputControlParameter) > 0)
    select 
    [GeoServices_Location].[GeographicServicesGatewayId],
    [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Lat,
    [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Long

    from GeoServices_Location

    inner join GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway
    on GeoServices_Location.GeographicServicesGatewayId = GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway.GeographicServicesGatewayId

    where 
    GeoServices_Location.GeographicServicesGatewayId in (select value from #T))
    and GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway.PrimarilyFoundOnLayerId IN(3,8,9,5) 
    option (recompile, querytraceon 8649)
else
    select
    [GeoServices_Location].[GeographicServicesGatewayId],
    [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Lat,
    [GeoServices_Location].[Coordinate].Long

    from GeoServices_Location with (index ([SPATIAL_GeoServices_Location]))

    inner join GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway
    on GeoServices_Location.GeographicServicesGatewayId = GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway.GeographicServicesGatewayId

    where 
    GeoServices_Location.Coordinate.STIntersects(@viewport) = 1
    and GeoServices_GeographicServicesGateway.PrimarilyFoundOnLayerId IN (3,8,9,5) 
    option (recompile, querytraceon 8649)
```

Comment: Dusan, this was a great suggestion.  So when I do it I get this error 'Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.'   This was very strange but lead me to this post; https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/12/09/spatial-index-is-not-used-when-subquery-used/   None of the 3 points cover this situation but #3 is close and describes our situation. Maybe we are on to something here? Having said that, the post refers to SQL Server 2008 which is where I am coming from.

Comment: I should also add that adding "with (index ([SPATIAL_GeoServices_Location]))" and running against Sql Server 2008 results in the same  'Query processor could not produce a..." error.

Comment: I see what you are experiencing now. I have edited answer with new proposal.

Comment: Dusan, this worked!  It made the query run instantly. Epic job! I guess my question is less about what I need to do to get this running quickly, rather my question is why does SQL Server 2016 with all its smarts just not run it quickly in the first place?  In other words, why did SQL Server 2016 choose to run a serial plan rather than a parallel plan?  Or more to the point, is this a bug in SQL Server 2016?  And which other queries do I have in my enormous database are now running more slowly than before?  Is there a global SQL Server 2016 switch to say "run queries in parallel"?

Comment: Hey sorry I didn’t respond earlier. You are right, by default the SQL Server should choose the best plan and run query as quickly as possible. The problem with this particular case may be the cardinality estimates but it may also be something else since a lot of changes were introduced since the 2008 version of server.

Comment: Regarding parallel plans, you can use dbcc traceon(8649, -1) to encourage them for all queries, but I wouldn’t advise that since the parallel plan is not always the fastest and some other queries may slow down. In this case did you also try running the query without forcing parallel plan?
If I understood correctly from your original post, your workload is running very fast with new server - so my advice would be to let SQL server chose plans by default and if you see some slow running queries (like this one) that have regressed with the new server you can work on speeding them up.

Answer (score 1):

1. check the growth of the data/log files on the new server (DBs) vs old server (DBs) configuration: the DB the query is running on + tempdb
2. check the log for I/O buffer errors
3. check recovery model of the DB's - simple vs full/bulk
4. is this a consistent behavior? maybe a process is running during the execution?
5. regarding statistics/indexes - are you sure it's running on correct data sample? (look at the plan)

many more things can be checked/done - but there is not enough info in this question.